# Unable to update Validator Commission

Tags: solana-test-validator

Getting stuck here trying to update a validators commission. Any help would be much appreciated

```
solana vote-update-commission -k authorized-withdrawer-keypair.json --fee-payer validator-keypair.json vote-account-keypair.json 7 authorized-withdrawer-keypair.json
    
    Error: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: missing required signature for instruction [2 log messages]
```

Comment: Very strange, this works on my side with 1.17.13. Are all of those files valid keypairs? And does `validator-keypair.json` have SOL to pay the fee? You can try removing the `-k` and `--fee-payer` arguments